# Windows Phone 8 offscreen Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I've got a problem when i'm trying to get a scrollable Canvas that is larger than screen size.
Actually, it works but canvas' background is always black, despite the fact that Backround property == "White".

Here is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="White" Width="4000" Height="4000">     
                <!-- Different UI elements -->                                   
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: What if you don't set the `Canvas` `Background` and set it to the `ScrollViewer` or `Grid` instead as a quick workaround?

Comment: @ChrisW.  I was trying to set ScrollViewer.Background but I had not deleted Canvas.Background. Now it works well, thanks!